# Auto upload MP4 files from phone to Ububtu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, sync

Is it possible for MP4 files to auto upload from my phone (Nexus 5, KitKat) into my Ubuntu One account?

Jpg files upload fine but MP4 just will not add to my Ubuntu One 'Nexus 5' folder. This functionality exists, and works, on Dropbox and Google+ so I do have a copy of the videos. It's a bit odd if this functionality didn't exisit on Ubuntu One so I assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus 5 is an Android phone, so you must be using Ubuntu One Files (Android) application to sync files between your phone and Ubuntu One Web. Assuming that you do, I am enlisting some  features of the Android app -

**Ubuntu One Files** (Android) application provides follwing features -

- Sync files from Ubuntu One Web to desktop and vice-versa
- Auto-upload images from Android to Ubuntu One Web when enabled.
- Selectively sync files / folders from desktop to Ubuntu One Web
- Download / Upload files or folders to and from Ubuntu One Files app on Android

---

However, it **does not** yet provide feature to -

- Auto-upload music files (*.mp4, *.mp3 etc.) or any other file types apart from pictures to Ubuntu One Web.
- Automatically sync updated file versions from Ubuntu One Files app to U1 Web or vice-versa.

In a nutshell, Ubuntu One Files app is still in a nascent stage as compared to Dropbox or Google+.

Be patient, and they will build it for you!